# Helpful flags should be colored as well as declined flags

Tags: feature-request, design, flag-history, helpful-flags

When a flag has been declined, it shows up in your flagging history like this:
[image]

But when your flag has been acknowledged as helpful, it shows like this: [image]

It makes sense that the "declined" is in red, but could we balance out the negative with positive?

Meaning that I am requesting that "helpful" flags show up as green (or a different 'positive' color) rather than black text.

We should be positive to users who flag correctly, not only coloring the negatives.